# 「些細な間違いの修正」と「些末な編集」の違いとは?

Tags: サポート

この度、信用度が1000を突破し、質問と回答を編集する権限を獲得しました。
そこで、[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)を読んでいたのですが、若干解りづらい点があったので質問です。

```
投稿を改善できると思い、そうしようと思ったらいつでもどうぞ。編集は推奨されます!
編集の一般的な理由は以下の通りです。
```

その理由の一つに以下が挙げられています。

```
・些細な間違いの修正や時間のたった投稿に補足や更新を追加する
```

しかし、その下には以下のようにあります。

```
細かい些末な編集は推奨されません。
```

私には言っていることが真逆に思えるのですが、細かい編集は推奨されるのかされないのか、どちらなのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

そこでいう編集は、サイトの編集機能を利用してリビジョンを追加すること、です。

まとめて修正すればいいものを細かく分けたり、あるいはしてもしなくてもいいような編集によって**むやみにリビジョンを増やすな**という話だと思います。そのヘルプに書かれた「1文字変更するだけではなく」というのがまさにその例です。

ですからまず、細かい問題点をまとめて修正するのは何の問題もありません。

また1文字の編集は全てダメというわけではなく、それが質問を大きく改善するもので、ほかに一緒に修正するものがなければ、それだけの編集を投稿しても構いません。

例えばサービス名や関数名などのtypoはある意味では些細なものですし、知っている人からすればほとんど気にも留めないかもしれません。でもよく知らない人が見て誤解したら？コピペして実行したら？と考えると、これを修正することには大きな意義があります（特に回答）。

※そもそも論旨が正しくないなどの**些細でない**間違いや、何を間違えたのか明確でない場合は、勝手に修正すべきではありません。コメントで指摘するか、正しい回答を別に投稿してください。

ちなみに原文では次のようになっています（該当箇所を太字にしています）。

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - ...
> - to **correct minor mistakes** or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - ...
>
> **Tiny, trivial edits** are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

#### 関連記事

- [Too minor edit reason can sometimes be a little contradictory - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116656/286934)
- [In Defense of Editing – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)
- [Why are trivial edits discouraged? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74430/286934)

Comment: 私は今まで、編集すると、編集内容の確認が権限のある人に投げられ、権限のある人の負荷が増えるため、どうでも良さそうな編集はすべきでない、と理解していました。従って、今回編集権限を獲得したことで、編集が他の人の確認なしに反映されるなら、誰の負荷も増やすことはないので、どうでも良さそうな編集でもできるようになったんだ、と一瞬思ったものの、ヘルプを見ると「推奨される」「推奨されない」と両方書いてあるように読めたので、質問させていただいたわけです。このヘルプが「むやみにリビジョンを増やすなという話」ということなので、その方針に従いますが、リビジョンをあまり増やすべきでないのはどういった理由なのでしょうか? やはり誰かに負荷をかけるのか、それともシステム負荷的問題でしょうか?

Comment: @masm 履歴の内容まで確認したい時に版が多いと面倒、bumpされるのでトップページの場所を取る、といった話もありますが、投稿者が編集内容を確認する手間が増える（通知もされます）というのは比較的大きいでしょうか。そもそも、**Wikiでもない他人の投稿を勝手に編集する以上、相応の理由があってしかるべき**でしょう。どうでもいい編集はつまり好みの問題ですから、そんな編集してくれるなという反感も招く可能性もあります。逆に、必要な修正を妨げるものではありません。些細な間違いの修正が些末ではないことが多いのは、回答に書いた通りです。

Comment: 理解しました。回答ありがとうございました。